# Why does Jesus side with Maggie in S08E16?

Tags: character, the-walking-dead

Jesus has always been the voice of mercy and reason in *The Walking Dead*, even in the last episode of S08E16 when he talks to Morgan.

In the last scene of S08E16, he agrees to this:

> Jesus agrees with Maggie's sinister plan to grow stronger and to teach Rick and Michonne a lesson. Basically to attack Alexandria to kill Negan. But her plan was not just limited to killing/assassinating Negan, but to betray her friends and allies, such a plan will result in definite bloodshed.

Maggie has her reasons, Daryl has his too, but why does Jesus agree with Maggie instead of trying to talk her out of it?

Comment: We don't know...this will probably be covered in the next series....although your assumptions as to Maggie's plans are not confirmed. They were **deliberately** non-specific.